# Create list of Callables of Monos of different types

Tags: java, generics

I have a method, which works with a list of `Callable` of `Mono` of different types.

How do I call it with `Callable<Mono<Integer>>` and `Callable<Mono<String>>` ?

I tried

```
void mymethod(List<Callable<Mono<?>>> monoList){

}

void yourMethod1() {
    Callable<Mono<Integer>> callableInt = () -> Mono.just(1);
    Callable<Mono<String>> callableStr = () -> Mono.just("Hello");

    List<Callable<Mono<?>>> callableList = Arrays.asList(callableInt,callableStr);

    mymethod(callableList);
}
```

but this does not compile with error `no instance(s) of type variable(s) exist so that Callable<Mono<Integer>> conforms to Callable<Mono<?>> inference variable T has incompatible bounds: equality constraints: Callable<Mono<?>> lower bounds: Callable<Mono<Integer>>, Callable<Mono<String>>`

How can I change `mymethod` or `yourMethod1` to get those objects in a list of `Mono` in `mymethod` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason your attempt doesn't compile is due to the fact that generic types in Java are not covariant. In other words, `Callable<Mono<Integer>>` and `Callable<Mono<String>>` are not considered subtypes of `Callable<Mono<?>>`, even though `Mono<Integer>` and `Mono<String>` are subtypes of `Mono<?>`.

So, first option to fix it:

```
void yourMethod1() {
    Callable<Mono<?>> callableInt = () -> Mono.just(1); // change type to Callable<Mono<?>>
    Callable<Mono<?>> callableStr = () -> Mono.just("Hello"); // change type to Callable<Mono<?>>

    List<Callable<Mono<?>>> callableList = Arrays.asList(callableInt, callableStr);

    mymethod(callableList);
}

void mymethod(List<Callable<Mono<?>>> monoList) {
}
```

Again, since `Mono<Integer>` and `Mono<String>` are subtypes of `Mono<?>`, the second option is to change `mymethod` argument to `List<Callable<? extends Mono<?>>>`:

```
void yourMethod1() {
    Callable<Mono<Integer>> callableInt = () -> Mono.just(1);
    Callable<Mono<String>> callableStr = () -> Mono.just("Hello");

    List<Callable<? extends Mono<?>>> callableList = Arrays.asList(callableInt, callableStr);

    mymethod(callableList);
}

void mymethod(List<Callable<? extends Mono<?>>> monoList) { // change type of argument
    // Your implementation here
}
```